# Custom css with supplemental-ui in Antora does not work

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor, antora

According to [UI-supplemental-files](https://docs.antora.org/antora/latest/playbook/ui-supplemental-files/) and [Stackoverflow antora-top-navigation-bar-customization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53691002/antora-top-navigation-bar-customization) I replaced my top navigation (`supplemental-ui/partials/header-content.hbs`), but the same thing for CSS doesn't work as expected.

Here is my folder structure, my `footer.css` in which I try to change the background to #fff, and my antora playbook where I add the supplemental folder path:

[image]

Footer background does not change to white.

Any suggestions why exchanging the *.hbs files work but *.css does not?

Edit: This is my `footer-content.hbs`:

```
<footer class="footer">
  <p>This page was built using the Antora default UI.</p>
  <p>The source code for this UI is licensed under the terms of the MPL-2.0 license.</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: The `supplemental_ui` feature does work for CSS. Is your generated site online? Or is the repo containing your `supplemental_ui` public? There may be something else that is confounding your configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should register your custom css file in 'head-styles.hbs' template.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{{uiRootPath}}}/css/site.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{{uiRootPath}}}/css/footer.css">
```